# Convert dictionary to tensors, and back

Tags: python, pytorch

I started with a dictionary object:

```
{"train": [{"input": [[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]], "output": [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]}, {"input": [[2, 3, 8], [2, 3, 8], [2, 3, 8]], "output": [[6, 4, 9], [6, 4, 9], [6, 4, 9]]}]}
```

I then want to add padding to each input and output object in a loop. So I converted each input and output to a tensor so I could then use  F.pad to add padding. Result of the first input:

```
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 3, 1, 2, 0],
        [0, 3, 1, 2, 0],
        [0, 3, 1, 2, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]).
```

result of the first output:

```
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 4, 5, 6, 0],
        [0, 4, 5, 6, 0],
        [0, 4, 5, 6, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

So that works fine.  Now, I want to reconstruct the generated tensors into the same form as the original dictionary, so that it will look like this:

```
{"train": [{"input": [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 1, 2, 0], [0, 3, 1, 2, 0], [0, 3, 1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], "output": [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 4, 5, 6, 0], [0, 4, 5, 6, 0], [0, 4, 5, 6, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]}, {"input": [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 3, 8, 0],
        [0, 2, 3, 8, 0],
        [0, 2, 3, 8, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], "output": [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 6, 4, 9, 0],
        [0, 6, 4, 9, 0],
        [0, 6, 4, 9, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]}]}
```

I can see a string concatenation way that might work:

`composedString = '{"train": [{"input": ' + tensor1 + tensor2`

or something like that. But given that there are different numbers of elements in the various arrays, it seems like a loop nightmare. I'm thinking there's got to be a better way. Anyone know what it is?

Comment: what is the shape of the input/output tensors you have before converting them back to dictionary?

Comment: Their shapes depend on the shape of the lists in the original dictionary object. So in the above example, the initial shape of the input was (3,3)  but after I added a padding of 1 (using zeroes) all around, it became torch.Size([5, 5])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following serve your purpose?

```
in_dict = {"train": [{"input": [[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]], "output": [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]}, {"input": [[2, 3, 8], [2, 3, 8], [2, 3, 8]], "output": [[6, 4, 9], [6, 4, 9], [6, 4, 9]]}]}

train_examples = []
for item in in_dict['train']:
    in_tensor = torch.Tensor(item['input'])
    out_tensor = torch.Tensor(item['output'])
    train_examples.append([in_tensor, out_tensor])

out_dict = {'train': []}
for item in train_examples:
    out_dict['train'].append({
        'input': item[0].tolist(),
        'output': item[1].tolist()
    })

print(out_dict)
```

Comment: Yes definitely, thanks!  I wanted to convert the numbers from floats back to integers and found the way to do that was simply to append .int() at the end; for example,     in_tensor = torch.Tensor(item['input']).int()